# I got a threatening email

Tags: email

I got an email saying:

> "We've been contacted because of your continued attempts at harassing
>   Broda and his friends. We're fans of him and we have his back. Delete
>   your twitter, delete your Youtube channel and do NOT attempt to
>   contact Broda ever again. Failure to do so will mean you become out
>   latest example. Lizard Squad."

And the email address is `lizardsquad@lizsquad.net`

Please tell me what to do. Should I trust it is real?!

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Where it is happening, at school, your aprox. age.

Comment: There isn't much here that we can tell you. You also do not provide any details (for instance, do you know this Broda? Have you been harassing this person?) There are ways to determine if the email is real, but I don't think people on the Internet can help. Find someone near you to investigate. Someone in an IT department should be able to help.

Comment: I removed  the screenshot because it had your phone number. The screenshot mentioned "Brook". Is it Broda or Brook? Do you know either of these people? We need more details like the questions I asked above.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is if you feel safe. If you feel it's necessary, I would send an e-mail and possibly do what they ask. However, I doubt the authenticity of the email for a few reasons.

1. They provide no evidence they are who they say they are. The From: part of an email can be faked fairly easily. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing.
2. If you actually try to go to http://www.lizsquad.net it can't be reached and seems to not exist. While the address could be just a mail server, that seems quite unlikely
3. The Lizard Squad twitter was shut down 1-1-17. See here: https://twitter.com/lizardlands.

While the whole thing seems quite unlikely to be legitimate, if you want you can certainly send them an email and see what, if anything, comes back.

Comment: It seems more a practical joke between kids...

Comment: It probably is just a joke. This is just my justification for thinking so.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a practical joke and/or misdirection. It is possible someone captured your credentials at a common PC you are both using, at faculty or school.

Google about 2FA and [Authy](https://www.authy.com) and starting using it in your smartphone, to authenticate both with your password AND with a numeric code. In that way, if someone gets hold of your password, it wont work without the numeric code.